# To design a library on top of conduits

Tags: haskell, conduit

Right now I'm developing a sort of ethernet packet processing library.
The basic idea is that there are two different sources for packets: 
network interfaces and pcap dump files. The packets should be grouped 
by flows, flows should be filtered, UDP flows should be processed by one
way, TCP by another way, etc.  I developed the version without conduits 
but I figured out that right now there is too much duplicated code and when
I'm trying to abstract then I'm inventing something similar to conduits. 
So I tried to switch to conduits and then stuck.

So the picture is like this:

```
                                   [UDP processing]
[pcap source]   |                 /                \
                |---[flow map]-->*                  *->[dump to many files]
                |                 \                /  
[iface source]  |                  [TCP processing]
```

The first problem is the flow map. It should accumulate 
flow and when there will be more packets in a flow than 
a some threshold - pass it to the processing.

The second problem is that I want to have different 
pipes for UDP and for TCP processing, so the pipe should 
be split somehow.

And another problem that all this stuff should be 
multithreaded, so producer and consumer should be 
in different threads.

So what in this picture should be what in terms of conduits?

Sources are sources, it's clear. But what should be
the flow map? A sink, that produces source for further 
processing? A number of flows is huge, so accumulating
all packets in memory before the further processing must
be avoided.

Any ideas? Again, it's quite clear how to do all of this without
the conduits, so the question is how to design it properly with them.

UPD.

```
  data FlowFrame = FlowFrame { flowKey   :: !F.FlowKey
                             , flowFrame :: [Packet]
                             }

  data FlowState

  flowFrames :: MonadIO m => Conduit Packet m FlowFrame
  flowFrames = awaitForever $ \p -> do
    let (Right (l3, _)) = runGet F.readL3Headers (pktData p)
    let fk = F.flowKey l3
    yield (FlowFrame fk [p])

  sinkPrintFlow :: MonadIO m => Consumer FlowFrame m ()
  sinkPrintFlow = awaitForever $ liftIO.putStrLn.show.pPrint.flowKey

  isA :: F.Protocol -> FlowFrame -> Bool
  isA p frame =
    case ((flowKey frame)) of
      F.FlowKey p _ _ -> True
      _               -> False

  processUDP :: MonadIO m => Conduit FlowFrame m FlowFrame
  processUDP = CL.filter (isA F.PROTO_UDP)

  processTCP :: MonadIO m => Conduit FlowFrame m FlowFrame
  processTCP = CL.filter (isA F.PROTO_TCP)

  main = do 
    (file:_) <- getArgs
    input <- openOffline file
    sourcePcap input
      $$ flowFrames =$= void (sequenceConduits [processUDP, processTCP])
      $= sinkPrintFlow
    putStrLn "done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different concepts you've mentioned. Let me answer each in turn:

- In order to coalesce two different sources into a single source, there are multiple choices. `ZipSource` is a common abstraction, but likely isn't what you're looking for. Since you probably want to do this concurrently, I'd recommend having each data source feed into a shared channel (e.g., a `TChan`) and then have a single `Source` reading from the channel. See [stm-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit) for more information.
- To get two different `Sink`s to read from a single `Source`, you can use `ZipSink`. This is likely the right answer in your case. You can filter the source down to just TCP and UDP data before fusing it with the relevant Sink.
- Normally all components of a pipeline run in a single thread (which is why we use coroutines). To be able to run your `Source`s and `Sink`s in separate threads, you can use [Data.Conduit.Async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-2.5.0/docs/Data-Conduit-Async.html) (also from stm-conduit).

In a situation like yours, it might make sense to be much more explicit about your usage of concurrency primitives under the surface, and have each data source or sink directly talk to a `TChan`. But that gets into some more complicated design issues, that I really can't give any definitive answer on with the current information.

(Nice flow diagram, by the way.)

Comment: Isn't ZipConduit better in this case? I saw the haddock, seems that it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pipes` then you can use the `(+++)` combinator from Pipes.Extras to run two pipes side by side.  It has this type:

```
(+++)
    :: Monad m
    => Pipe a c m r
    -> Pipe b d m r
    -> Pipe (Either a b) (Either c d) m r
```

Then your program would become:

```
producer >-> (udpPipe +++ tcpPipe) >-> consumer
```

Every time you want the producer to forward a value to the `udpPipe` you wrap the value in a `Left` and every time you want to forward a value to the `tcpPipe` you wrap the value in a `Right`.  The downstream `consumer`  then can pattern match on its input to tell which `Pipe` it came from.  `Left` values came from `udpPipe` and `Right` values came from `tcpPipe`.

Edit: Note that this requires no concurrency.  `(+++)` takes two single-threaded pipes and returns a new single threaded pipe that combines their logic.

Comment: ok, but what if there are more than two alternatives? Say, TCP, UDP and ICMP for an instance. Just interesting, it's not my case right now.

Comment: If you keep chaining `(+++)` you will get nested eithers.  For example, `p1 +++ (p2 +++ p3)` will give you a `Pipe (Either a (Either b c)) (Either d (Either e f)) m r`.  It's verbose to deal with, but it works.  You can also define an ADT with 3 constructors and convert back and forth between the nested eithers and your custom ADT by putting `map` pipes before and after your parallel pipes.